# If F satisfiable then ¬F is unsatisfiable.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, satisfiability

If F satisfiable then ¬F is unsatisfiable. I know this is false and to show this I need to show a contradiction, this is my attempted answer, any ideas where I'm going wrong, this is revision for an exam.

```
[A]α = ¬(¬[A]))
     = ¬([A])
     = ¬ (0)
     = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

In propositional logic, a formula $F$ is [*satisfiable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability) when there is a [valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(logic)) (or : truth-assignment) $v$ such that $v(F)=$ **t** (in first-order logic : when there is an *interpretation* that makes the formula true).

This does not implies that its negation is *unsatisfiable*.

Consider the simple example of a formula $F := p$, where $p$ is a sentential letter.

Clearly $F$ is sat, and also $\lnot F$ is sat.

But there are many more : $p \lor q, p \to q, p \land q, \ldots$

---

The interesting relation is :

> if a formula $F$ is *unsatisfiable*, then $\lnot F$ is a *tautology* (i.e. always *true*).

Comment: what do you mean by that example p  is a sentential letter?

Comment: @Octavian - it is the formula $p$ (made of one only symbol).