# What is negation of a tautology?

Tags: logic, terminology

I was learning concepts of tautology, contradiction, contingent etc. The [Tautology page of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)) has following statement:

> A formula is satisfiable if it is true under at least one interpretation, and thus a tautology is a formula whose negation is unsatisfiable.

Q1. Is the last part wrong? A statement that is not a tautology can either be a contradiction (which is unsatisfiable) or contingent, but it is not always unsatisfiable. Right?

Q2. I believe that the negation of a satisfiable statement is (obviously) unsatisfiable. Right? (And I believe thats what author of wiki article meant to say, but made a mistake and said that negation of tautology is unsatisifiable.)

Comment: Q2. NO; a negation of a *satisfiable* formula is **not** necessarily *unsatisfiable*. See the post [If F satisfiable then ¬F is unsatisfiable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3075900/if-f-satisfiable-then-%c2%acf-is-unsatisfiable)

Comment: So, Yes to Q1? Also negation of satisfiable need not be unsatisfiable as satisifable can be a contingent whose negation is also contingent but not contradiction / unsatisfiable. Right?

Comment: "Not a tautology".  2 meanings. "The negation of a tautology" and "Not a statement that can be categorized as a tautology".  Wikipedia means the first.  You are acting on the second.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia hasn't made a mistake on this.

In classical logic, the models that satisfy a formula are precisely those that don't satisfy its negation. Thus a tautology is satisfied in all models and its negation - a contradiction - is satisfied in none, and that's what we mean when we say it's unsatisfiable. A contingent formula is satisfi*able*, but whether it's satis*fied* depends on the model.

Comment: If tautology = satisfied for all models, then negation of tautology = not satisfied for all models. That means (I) it might be satisfied for some models but not all or (II) satisfied for no model. (I) is contingent (II) is unsatisfiable / contradiction. So negation of tautology is a set containing contingent and contradiction, but "not just contradiction". Negation of satisfable is contradiction / unsatisfiable. Otherwise, both satisfiable and tautology will mean the same.

Comment: (continued from earlier comment) I prepared [this](https://i.postimg.cc/CxbqmsrQ/tauto.jpg) diagram. Is it correct? It also shows, negation of tautology = contingent + contradiction (but not just contradiction).

Comment: @anir The first sentence in your first comment shows a confusion; you've negated a statement *about* a statement, but I was talking about how the models satisfying a formula compare with those satisfying that formula's negation. Formulae are tautological when satisfied in all models, contradictions when in none, and contingent when in some but not all; and negatinga  formula exchanges between the first two options.

Answer (score 1):

Defintion: $\varphi$ is satisfiable if there exists an interpretation $\mathfrak{M}\models\varphi$, and unsatisfiable if in every interpretation $\mathfrak{M}$, we have $\mathfrak{M}\not\models \varphi$.

Definition: $\varphi$ is a tautology if for every interpretation $\mathfrak{M}$, we have $\mathfrak{M}\models\varphi$.

Definition: $\varphi$ is a contradiction if for every interpretation $\mathfrak{M}$, we have $\mathfrak{M}\not\models\varphi$, i.e., if $\varphi$ is unsatisfiable.

Lemma: $\mathfrak{M}\models \varphi$ if and only if $\mathfrak{M}\not\models\neg\varphi$.

Observation: $\varphi$ is a contradiction if and only if $\varphi$ is unsatisfiable.

Theorem: $\varphi$ is a tautology if and only if $\neg\varphi$ is not satisfiable.

Proof: ($\Rightarrow$) If $\varphi$ is a tautology then for all $\mathfrak{M}$, we have $\mathfrak{M}\models \varphi$, so by the Lemma, for all $\mathfrak{M}$, we have $\mathfrak{M}\not\models\neg\varphi$, so $\neg\varphi$ is unsatisfiable.

($\Leftarrow$) If $\neg\varphi$ is unsatisfiable, then for all $\mathfrak{M}$ we have $\mathfrak{M}\not\models \neg\varphi$, so by the Lemma, for all $\mathfrak{M}$ we have $\mathfrak{M}\models \varphi$. Therefore $\varphi$ is a tautology. $\square$

> A statement which is not a tautology can be either contingent or contradiction,

Yes.

> that is unsatisfiable, but it cannot be always unsatifiable.

Either a statement is satisfiable or it is unsatisfiable (which is to say, not satisfiable). There is no such thing as "always unsatisfiable".

> Q2. I believe "negation of satisfiable statement is (obviously) unsatisfiable". Right? (And I believe thats what author of wiki article meant to say, but made a mistake and said negation of tautology is unsatisifiable.)

No. The negation of a satisfiable statement can still be satisfiable. "It is cold" is satisfiable, its negation "it is not cold" is also satisfiable, as long as you allow that there are some things which are cold and some (other) things which are not cold.

Comment: Isnt contradiction and unsatisfiable same? Both are always false for any interpretation. You said "Yes" to "contingent or contradiction". That means it (negation of tautology) cannot be always contradiction / unsatisifiable, but can also be contingent. (Q.I) In short I feel, satisfiable = contingent + tautology and unsatisfiable = contradiction.

Comment: (continued from earlier comment) (Q.II.) I believe, if it is cold, then it (same thing) cannot be warm at the same time. I believe we never talk about group of things in logic to allow some things to be cold and some not cold. Multiple "component" things may make up one thing. That is given X = Y + Z, we talk about whether X is tautology / contradiction etc. not about Y or Z.

Comment: If you believe that there is a thing which is cold, then you believe that "it is cold" is satisfiable. If you believe that there is anything that is not cold, then you believe that "it is not cold" is satisfiable. Obviously both of these two sentences are never jointly satisfied by the same thing. But they are both satisfiable, by different things.

Comment: Yeah I got that negation of satisfiable need not be unsatisfiable as satisifable can be a contingent whose negation is also contingent. Right? Also you said "Yes" to "A statement which is not a tautology can be either contingent or contradiction". Should I interpret this as wikipedia is wrong with "tautology is a formula whose negation is unsatisfiable"

Comment: No, you did not get that. You specifically said << I believe "negation of satisfiable statement is (obviously) unsatisfiable" >>. Wikipedia is correct. A tautology is a formula which is satisfied in every interpretation. If an interpretation satisfies a formula, then it does not satisfy the negation of that formula. Therefore, a tautology is a formula whose negation is not satisfied in every interpretation, i.e., a tautology is a formula whose negation is not satisfiable.

Comment: `There is no such thing as "always unsatisfiable"` this is wrong, there exist a formula that is always unsatisfiable, such formula are called contradiction

Comment: @LLL Did you even read the answer? Your comment is a non-sequitur. What the sentence means in context, as made incredibly clear in the answer if you had read it, is that there is no special concept called "always unsatisfiable" as distinct from "unsatisfiable", or as distinct from "a contradiction". The OP was confused because he thought that "unsatisfiable" and "always unsatisfiable" were two distinct concepts. They aren't. "Unsatisfiable" is one concept, and "always unsatisfiable" isn't a concept at all, it's a malapropism.

Comment: @MarcelBesixdouze i know, but in my opinion it is still wrong to write that there is no such thing as always unsatisfiable because it might confuse (and probably mislead) reader that do not fully understand the answer

Comment: @LLL Well, we have at least one example, literally right here, where the phrase "always unsatisfiable" was the source of confusion of the reader. A reader who does not fully understand an answer is by definition confused. My goal is to provide an answer that, if they take the time to understand, will alleviate them of all confusion. "Always unsatisfied" is okay, and "unsatisfiable" is okay, but "always unsatisfiable" would only ever sound acceptable to someone who is completely confused.

Answer (score 0):

$p \lor (\lnot p)\equiv \top\;\;$  is a tautology in classical logic.

No matter what truth value we assign to $p$, the statement is true.

It's negation:

\begin{align} \lnot(p \lor (\lnot p))&\equiv (\lnot p \land \lnot(\lnot p))\tag{DeMorgan's}\\ \\
&\equiv (\lnot p \land p)\tag{double negation}\\ \\
&\equiv \bot\end{align}

is a contradiction.  It doesn't matter whether $p$ is true or false, the negation of the tautology $p \lor (\lnot p)$ is false.

If $\top$ designates a tautology, then $\lnot \top \equiv \bot$, where $\bot$ designates a contradition.

---

With respect to satisfiability, the formula $p \to q$ is contingent: it is satisfiable for all truth-value assignments to p, q, *except* for  the assignment where $p$ is true, and $q$ is false.

The negation of $p \to q$ is given by $\lnot (p \to q) \equiv \lnot(\lnot p \lor q) \equiv (p \land \lnot q).$  It is also contingent because it is satisfiable only when $p$ is true and $q$ is false.

So both $(p\to q)$, and $\lnot(p\to q)$ are satisfiable, but contingent.

Just remember that the negation of a satisfiable formula does not mean the negated formula is unsatisfiable.  It is **only** when a formula is a tautology, satisfiable under *every truth value assingment*, that the negation of the formula/tautology is a contradiction, and unsatisfiable under any truth value assignment.

Answer (score 0):

> A statement that is not a tautology can either be a contradiction (which is unsatisfiable) or contingent, but it is not always unsatisfiable. Right?

Indeed,

1. **every statement that is not a tautology** is some contingency or contradiction.

However,

2. **the negation of every tautology** is some contradiction, which *is* always unsatisfiable.

   [Remember, negation is a logical operation, which means that it has the same effect on a formula (flipping its truth value) regardless of interpretation; so, since a tautology is a formula whose truth-functional form is true regardless of interpretation, its negation's truth-functional form must be false regardless of interpretation, i.e., its negation must be a contradiction.]

> I believe that the negation of a satisfiable statement is (obviously) unsatisfiable. Right?

No: $\forall x\,P(x)$ and its negation are *both* satisfiable.

---

Your misunderstanding arises from conflating taking **the complement of a set** (point #1) and taking **the negation of a statement** (point #2).

Full explanation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4518468/21813).